# How can I detect if the size of something has changed with floating point precision deficiencies?

Tags: floating-point, precision

Imagine I have a rectangle with sides specified by left, right, top, bottom. Then:

```
myrect.left = 5.5
myrect.right = 21.32

xSizeBeforeTranslation = myrect.right - myrect.left

translation = 50.0

myrect.left += translation
myrect.right += translation

xSizeAfterTranslation == xSizeBeforeTranslation // This is false, though under what circumstances I don't know
```

I need to find out if the size of the rectangle changed after coming out of a function. The simplest solution, to detect whether the top/bottom or left/right translations are equal, won't work in my case because my function isn't really doing translations. What it's doing is calculating the layout of a rect nside another rect, then sets the edge values. There are many if statements based on the sizing rules of the rect and its relation to others, so I'm pretty sure there's no way to do that.

I can set a tiny threshold so that if the before size is within a tolerance of of after size it can be considered the same, but this means that my program won't be reacting to really small changes, which when summed up can be important.

Comment: Suppose it is feasible to determine whether the differences between the coordinates are equal (exactly with real-number arithmetic, not just with floating-point arithmetic). Is that the test you want? It would produce false if your routine attempted to calculate coordinates with equal differences if computed with real-number arithmetic but that have unequal differences due to floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: For example, using three-digit decimal for illustration, suppose the ideal left and right coordinates were 1.005 and 8.015 in one square and 2.015 and 9.025 in the other. Both pairs differ by 7.01. But the three-digit decimal floating-point results computed with the common round-to-nearest ties-to-even method would produce 1.00 and 8.02 for one pair and 2.02 and 9.02 for the other, with differences of 7.02 and 7.00. The exact test would produce false. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of floating point. You don't say whether you are using single or double precision, so I'll assume double.

Roughly speaking, you have 3 choices.

1. Use an absolute tolerance, for instance a factor of 1e6 smaller than your largest expected values. Absolute tolerances are not good if your data has a very large range.
2. Use a relative tolerance, for instance 1e3 times the larger of the abs values of the two values being compared. Relative tolerances are good at handling large ranges but poor if you have very small values that should be considered as zero.
3. Both of the above.

You may also have access to arbitrary precision calculations, which could also
be a solution.

Whatever you choose, it's important to adapt it to the range of your data.
And don't then blindly apply tolerances to each and every kind of comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows how the differences of floating-point numbers can be exactly compared.

```
#include <math.h>


/*  Define a structure to hold a pair of numbers we use to represent a sum
    exactly.
*/
typedef struct { double s, t; } SumPair;


/*  If floating-point arithmetic with subnormals and round-to-nearest is used,
    Fast2Sum produces the exact sum of a and b; it produces s and t such that
    s+t (calculated with real-number arithmetic, not floating-point arithmetic)
    equals a+b and s = RN(a+b) (the sum of a and b computed with floating-point
    arithmetic using round-to-nearest).

    Jean-Michel Muller et al, Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic (Birkhäuser
    Boston, 2010), pages 125 to 129.
*/
static SumPair Fast2Sum(double a, double b)
{
    //  If needed, swap a and b to ensure a has larger or equal magnitude.
    if (fabs(b) > fabs(a))
    {
        double t = a;
        b = a;
        a = t;
    }

    double s = a+b; //  Find the representable value nearest the sum.
    double z = s-a; //  s-a is exact by Sterbenz' Lemma.
    double t = b-z; //  Find the difference between s and the exact sum.
    return (SumPair) {s, t};
}


/*  Return true if and only if the distance from l0 to r0 equals the distance
    from l1 to r1, with real-number mathematics regardless of floating-point
    errors.
*/
static _Bool DistancesAreEqual(double l0, double r0, double l1, double r1)
{
    //  Find the exact difference of r0 and l0.
    SumPair d0 = Fast2Sum(r0, -l0);

    //  Find the exact difference of r1 and l1.
    SumPair d1 = Fast2Sum(r1, -l1);

    //  Return true if and only if the two differences are equal.
    return d0.s == d1.s && d0.t == d1.t;
}
```